# How to put message as key value pair on topic using apache kafka in steam processing

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to put key value pair message to topic in kafka. I am taking input from one topic in stream customizing mesaage and then trying to put on another topic. Can anybody tell how to put Message to destination topic in java?